# In scheme, how do I determine if the characters in the lists I have are changing

Tags: scheme, racket

In scheme, how do I determine if the characters in the lists I have are changing

Answer (score 1):

```
(define (increasing-character-numbers? strings)
  "Return true if number of characters are increasing"
  (cond ((< (length strings) 2) #f)
        (t (apply < (map string-length strings))))

;; or use an `and` for such kind of conditions:
(define (increasing-character-numbers? strings)
  (and (< 1 (length strings)) (apply < (map strings-length strings))))

> (increasing-character-numbers? '("a" "aa" "aaa"))
#t
> (increasing-character-numbers? '("aaa" "a"))
#f
> (increasing-character-numbers? '("a" "a"))
#f
```

`(map string-length strings)`
determines the number of characters in each of the strings in the list `strings`.
The lisp magic is in `(apply < char-nums-in-strings)`.
It takes the list of character numbers and adds in front of it the `<` function to ask whether they are in increasing order to each other from left to the right. If the number of characters stays equal between two neighbours - it will return already `#f`.

One can tolerate such cases by `<=`.

```
(apply <= '(1 2 2 3 3 3 4)) ;; => #t
(apply <= '(1 2 2 3 4 3))`  ;;=> #f
```

## changing characters

After changing your original question - I would answer to that:

```
(define (characters-changing? strings)
  (and (< 1 (length strings)) (not (apply string=? strings))))
```

Comment: But apparently `(increasing-character-numbers '("a"))` is required to => `#f` ?

Comment: May be adding a `cond` should suffice.

Comment: @mnemenaut and @NalinRanjan true, I added a `cond`.